# What is the GUID for load test

Tags: node.js, botframework, load-testing, azure-bot-service

I am trying to do a load test on a chat bot that I deployed on Microsoft Azure bot service, and I am following the blog post on here: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/,
I am able to finish the first step, I am able to get auth token and get Mock channel, but for the last step:
it states:

```
    {
  "type": "message",
  "id": <GUID>,
  "channelId" : "test", 
  "conversation": { "id": <CONVERSATION ID> },
  "from": { "id": <USER ID> },
  "recipient": { "id": <BOT HANDLE> },
  "serviceUrl": <SEE BELOW> 
}
```

I know service URL is the endpoint of the mock channel. but for all other Id, I don't know where can I get it?
Can anyone help me with this? give me some guidance on how to get all those ids?

Thanks a lot.
Node.js

Comment: if you're using C#, you can generate a GUID using Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

Comment: Guid will be in this format : 2f829efd-51c4-45df-a837-e88002cd62e8

Comment: I am using node.js.....anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: Just one more question: In my understanding the user Id and conversation id, bot id doesn't matter in this case, I can set them to any value. right?

Comment: Yes you can, but each Id should be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the mock channel doesn't work again...I went to the github: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/blog-samples/CSharp/MockChannel , what shall I deploy it as ? I tried to deploy it as api app, it doesn't work, the postman tell me there is 500 internal error.

Comment: @QiLin, did you deploy the the mock channel repository to api app? you can try to deply to Azure Web Apps, you can refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-web-app-to-azure-using-visual-studio/ for how to deploy C# applications to Azure Web App. Looking forward to your update.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT  The way I did is zip deployment, Today, I tried to deploy it as api app by github, it gives this error during build : This project references NuGet package(s), I also tried the to deploy it as web app by github, It gives the same error.  I also try to open on Visual studio and build it, it gives the same error. I search about it and tried few ways to resolve it, but it only gives more complex error. I never use C# so can you please help me out on this. Thanks

Comment: It seems that you missed to install NuGet packages, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/ways-to-install-a-package for more details.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I already fixed the error....but it still gives me 500 error, My post request Body: {
  "type": "message",
  "id": "someid",
  "channelId" : "test", 
  "conversation": { "id": "test1"  },
  "from": { "id": "test1user" },
  "recipient": { "id": "test1bot" },
  "serviceUrl": "mockchanne urll"
}. Now I think I missed some setting on the mock application setting

Comment: Now there isn't any error when I deploy, but when I access the page it give a message: sorry you do no have permission, after all I don't really understand this mock channel, if possible can you explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all these by inspecting an activity from your bot, then plugging in valid values in your mock channel for sending the activity.  You can get these values by setting a breakpoint at any other point in your process that sends/receives or handles an activity.  Just inspect the values and use them accordingly.  Remember to do things like switch the from and recipient where needed.

I know you are asking for JavaScript but this is an example of how I am constructing and activity in my mock channel using c#:

```
Activity a = new Activity
{
    Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
    Id = "9dn3fa6lh4hd9dn3fa6lh4hd",
    ChannelId = Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ChannelIds.Console,
    Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: "9dn3fa6lh4hd"),
    From = new ChannelAccount(id: "user", name: "username"),
    Recipient = new ChannelAccount(id: "bot", name: "botname"),
    Text = "Mock Channel",
    ServiceUrl = @"http://localhost:55086/api/values",
    MembersAdded = new List<ChannelAccount>(),
    MembersRemoved = new List<ChannelAccount>(),
    Locale = "en-US",
    Attachments = new List<Attachment>(),
    ReplyToId = "nii4344blg42",
    TextFormat = "plain",
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
    ChannelData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { clientActivityId = "1506483656068.11949484894092266.2" })
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can get all the id now. But the problem is that the sample mock channel doesn't work.I tried to deploy it as api app by github, it gives this error during build : This project references NuGet package(s), I also tried the to deploy it as web app by github, It gives the same error. I also try to open on Visual studio and build it, it gives the same error. I search about it and tried few ways to resolve it, but it only gives more complex error.

Comment: Where are you getting the sample project from?

Comment: I tried to use the sample from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/blog-samples/CSharp/MockChannel

Comment: I think fixed the error....but it still gives me 500 error, My post request Body: {
  "type": "message",
  "id": "someid",
  "channelId" : "test", 
  "conversation": { "id": "test1"  },
  "from": { "id": "test1user" },
  "recipient": { "id": "test1bot" },
  "serviceUrl": "mockchanne urll"
}. Now I think I missed some setting on the application setting

Comment: Now there isn't any error when I deploy, but when I access the page it give a message: sorry you do no have permission, after all I don't really understand this mock channel, if possible can you explain it

Comment: Let me take a look at this mockChannel you used when I get a chance. The basic Idea is that it is just an endpoint that receives and sends messages like a channel would.